Where does the energy in ion propulsion come from?
Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm currently trying to learn about electric and ion propulsion.
I understand that for chemical propulsion, the energy released from the chemical bonds during the chemical reaction is what is converted into thrust. But for ion propulsion, where does the energy come from. Does the energy come from the power source and the propellant is simply a vessel to transfer energy to thrust? Or is the energy released when the propellant is ionized? Or do I have this completely wrong?
Thanks and I appreciate all responses.

Ion thrusters in spacecraft use electrical energy to ionize the propellant and then accelerate it.  The electrical energy comes from comes from solar panels. Propellant is expelled from the rear of the craft. Conservation of momentum causes forward motion of the spacecraft.


Does the energy come from the power source and the propellant is simply a vessel to transfer energy to thrust?

Yes, you've got it exactly right!
For ion propulsion, one takes advantage of the charge of the ions. That allows an electric field to push them without needing to otherwise heat them.
They certainly may get a little hot in the process of ionizing them, but those ~eV thermal velocities are nothing compared to the velocities now possible by accelerating the ions to 10 or 100 keV or more.
To maintain ionization, the pressure needs to be low to avoid collisions and recombination with electrons (thereby becoming neutral) before they can be accelerated by the high voltage.
Since the electric fields are already pointing primarily straight back out of the thruster, you don't need a nozzle2.
If you release say (just for a numerical example) $6 \times 10^{18}$ ions per second, each with a +1 charge, that's a Coulomb per second, or 1 amp of ion current1. If you use a voltage of 10 kV to accelerate it, that would require 10 kW of electrical power.
That's not all the electrical power required, a comparable amount is also needed to maintain the plasma where the ions come from.
And we should also never forget that it's not the energy, but the momentum of the ions that results in thrust.
Now, where the electricity comes from has some flexibility. Generally it's either solar panels, or far from the Sun, it can be from Radioisotope thermoelectric generators (see the rtg tag).
For more on that see:

Mass ratio of solar-electric versus radioisotope thermo-electric power for propulsion; beyond how many AU do RTGs win?
At some point far from the Sun does the output of solar panels start dropping much faster than inverse square? If so, how fast?
How far from the Sun can solar power be used as a reliable energy source?
What is the status of concentrated solar energy (CSE) in space exploration?
Lightest possible solar array?


1To avoid a rapid unscheduled disassembly due to a "Coulomb explosion" there is also 1 amp of electrons being emitted by an electron gun to keep the charge of the spacecraft close to neutral. cf Is there any possible reason to direct the electron gun specifically towards the ion trail behind an ion thruster?
2So how do you steer without a nozzle to gimbal? Gimbal the whole ion engine! See answers to Thrust vectoring for ion propulsion - any plans or current research? and How does MEV use its "ion thruster on a stick" technology?

Gotcha. I believe I understand what you're getting at. So the only possible way to increase the mass flow rate is to increase the input power?

@Matthew how ion thrusters perform as a function of gas flow rate, pressure, RF or DC power used to produce the plasma, and species (what kinds of atoms) is a complicated topic. The thrust will generally increase as the square root of the acceleration voltage, so a factor of 10 in voltage gives you a factor of 3 in thrust. But ion thrusters are carefully designed and optimized to work in a certain range of operating conditions and can loose efficiency (specific impulse to be exact) if you go outside of that range. I can see you are ready to ask a new question, so post it so others see it too!

The part starting with 10^15 ions per second is misleading, because it's not what typical ion thrusters do.   A value of 10^19 ions and 1 kW would be much more typical. And the power to maintain the plasma is less than the power used for acceleration. Power efficiency is somewhere between 50 and 80%.

@asdfex thanks! I've done some rewriting. I've also just asked What is the largest and smallest ion thruster proper used in 21st century spaceflight in our solar system?
